# How to run python coding in anaconda prompt using vba?

Tags: python, vba, anaconda

I am attempting to run python coding using vba.
However, when running using vba, it was not successful .
(i discovered that it is not running in anaconda prompt)

the code is attached as follow. appreciate the help.

```
Sub RunPythonScript()

Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExePath As String, PythonScriptPath As String

Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    
PythonExePath = """C:xxx.exe"""
PythonScriptPath = """C:xxx.py"""
    
objShell.Run PythonExePath & " " & PythonScriptPath
    
End Sub
```

Alternatively, I manually run in anaconda prompt and the code works.

`"C:xxx.exe" "C:xxx.py"`

What I observed on screen was the black cmd window pop out and disappeared in second. It did not work as expected. Is there anything I input incorrectly?

```
Sub RunPythonScript()
Dim pythonExePath As String, pythonScriptPath As String

pythonExePath = """C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\python.exe"""
pythonScriptPath = """C:\Users\xxx\xxx.py"""

Shell pythonExePath & " " & pythonScriptPath, vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try both of these and feedback with your results.

```
Public Sub PythonOutput()

    Dim oShell As Object, oCmd As String
    Dim oExec As Object, oOutput As Object
    Dim arg As Variant
    Dim s As String, sLine As String

    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    arg = "somevalue"
    oCmd = "python ""C:\Users\ryans\from_vba.py""" ' & " " & arg

    Set oExec = oShell.Exec(oCmd)
    Set oOutput = oExec.StdOut

    While Not oOutput.AtEndOfStream
        sLine = oOutput.ReadLine
        If sLine <> "" Then s = s & sLine & vbNewLine
    Wend

    Debug.Print s

    Set oOutput = Nothing: Set oExec = Nothing
    Set oShell = Nothing

End Sub


Sub RunPython()

Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String
    
    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    PythonExe = """C:\Users\ryans\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe"""
    PythonScript = "C:\Users\ryans\from_vba.py"
    
    objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript
    
End Sub
```

Comment: 1. What shall I input for "arg"?
2. There is a single quotation mark in "oCmd", is it a typo?